# Sails.js - User Management and CRUD. Completed projects to reuse? (to not reinvent the wheel)

Tags: sails.js, acl, crud

I'm using a bit Sails just to see how it works. What a great job! You all are great.

But I have a question: is there any plans to have CRUD functionality and user management (although basic)?

Well, I mean, to the concept that it is not worth reinventing (or rewrite) the wheel, I would love if someone had already invented a similar project to Drupal (similar, I emphasize) for Sails.

In doing so we commit ourselves programmers more on the code of our application and not on code that will definitely bugs on bugs over time to create an incredibly strong code for those features that are used more or less by all.

Am I wrong?

Request: I am looking for something (even more projects to be merged) that allow me to manage users (registration, login, encrypted passwords, permissions ACL), CRUD (data categories, mongodb preferable).

I'm sure someone already thought of it before me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this will not happen, since Sails seems to take the stance not to make implementation choices for you.

Try a search for "sails" at NPM. I think I have seen a couple of demo applications uploaded to NPM.